# o.lettuce.core.RedisException::io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError while retrieving a big object(2MB)from Redis

Tags: spring-boot, redis, netty, spring-data-redis

I  have a Springboot application that connects to Redis cache ( Azure redis) and retrieve an object . The object size is 2MB . I am getting the following error some times .

> io.lettuce.core.RedisException:
>   io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate
>   524288000 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 553648128, max:
>   1073741824)"}.

It is not happening every time .  Why it is allocating 524288000 byte(s) to retrieve a 2MB object ? When it is working , I get the response in 1 sec .

Details :

Spring boot version : 2.1.5

Spring data redis : 2.1.8

Lettuce core : 5.1.6

io.Netty : 4.1.36

Deployment environment Deatils :

Enviornment: Pivotal Cloud Foundry environment

Memory : 2GB with a direct memory of 1GB

Redis :

Azure Premium Redis with 6GB memory.

Code snippet :

To retrieve the object , I am using the following piece of code :

`redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(keyname);`

and then convert to the Object using an ObjectMapper.

and all default properties .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the allocation seems to happen as part of lettuce I would suggest opening a bug report there. This does not sounds correct.

Comment: Thanks @Norman . Actually I changed the Lettuce connection configuration to Jedis configuration and application is working fine . So as you said , it looks like an issue with Lettuce